# How to know if the pub/sub topic contains messages with specific content?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have X micro-services each of them are them are publishing to the same pub/sub topic. The messages they publish contain the micro-service ID.
I am looking for a way to make sure that the pub/sub has finished servicing all the messages of a certain micro-service.
My current solution is to count all the messages that were published from the micro-service, and then count the messages that were served in the pub/sub topic (via cloud-function). There are some known issues with this approach, and I was wondering if there is a better way to know if the pub/sub does not contain messages from the specific micro-service?

Comment: It seems that logical would be to publish them to separate topics... why you are publishing them to the same topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with is as follows:

1. create a *set* in redis, and add a new message id to it
2. Include this new message id in the message published to the pubsub
3. the cloud function that runs after the pubsub should remove the new message_id from the set
4. by the end of the process, we check the set and if it is empty then the process is done.

This also handle the times when pub/sub publish the same message more than once.

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution to know the content of a message than getting the message, opening it and reading it.

A better solution could be to use a separate topic for each type of message, and is the subscription queue is empty, that means all the message have been processed. If you need to count them, you can use the logs to track your message processing in Cloud FUnctions.

An alternative is to use a single PubSub topic and to add the ID in attribute of the message. Then you can create PubSUb subscription with a filter on that attribute and to oversee the subscription as before.

The bad side of that solution is that it's not compliant with Cloud Functions PubSub integration. You need to create an HTTP functions and a PubSub push subscription to be able to leverage the filter feature.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution, but it wont work in our case, since we do have a lot of micro-services running at the same time. Sometimes they are small and end fast and it would be an overkill to provision a pub/sub for each one.